# Glassfish: Deploying an application using a unique port

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, jersey, glassfish-3

Currently we're using Glassfish 3 and have 3 Network-Listeners,
Admin,
HTTP, &
HTTPS.

So obviously there are 3 unique ports assigned to these listeners.

The problem we are having is that we need to assign our new java EE application (.ear) to a new port for security reasons, as there are too many applications already using the default ports.

I have no idea how to do this.
Do I need to make a new network-listener and specify the port that listener will use? How do I specify that my application uses this port/listener when deployed?

I should also mention that we'll still be using the default domain.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make a new virtual server under server-config and a new network listener for the new port you're going to use.

In the settings for the old virtual server, make sure that you do not include your new network listener. In the new virtual server, make sure you only include your new network listener.

When you deploy the application, there will be a list box where you can select which virtual server you want to assign that application to.